# Boil kettle from plastic fermentation bin

Tags: equipment, boil-kettle, boil-equipment

Can a plastic fermentation bin be modified with a heater element to make a strike-water heater or a boil-kettle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it has been done many times.

Comment: Do you have any good links on what heater element, how how get a good seal or is it as simple as attaching a tap?

Comment: Not off hand.  Take a look at the AHA and Northern Brewer forums.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that most of the plastic fermentation buckets are only rated up to 170F. Boiling water in it would probably warp the bucket.